# OpenSUSE MicroOS fails to start on OpenStack

Tags: openstack, opensuse, cloud-init, coreos-ignition, immutable

I'm testing some operating systems cloud images to be used on OpenStack. I'm trying OpenSUSE MicroOS with the following butane configuration:

```yaml
---
variant: fcos
version: 1.1.0
storage:
  filesystems:
    # Mount /home folder (required when creating non-root users)
    - device: /dev/disk/by-label/ROOT
      path: /home
      format: btrfs
      wipe_filesystem: false
      mount_options:
        - "subvol=/@/home"
  files:
    # give a name to the instance
    - path: /etc/hostname
      mode: 0644
      overwrite: true
      contents:
        inline: ${hostname}
passwd:
  users:
    # Define a password for root user
    - name: root
      password_hash: ${root_pass}
    # Create a new non-root user
    - name: ${username}
      ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ${ssh_pub_key}
```

I render this configuration to ignition and then I pass it to the instance user_data.. It works with Fedora CoreOS, Flatcar Linux and Ubuntu cloud-init, but MicroOS instance does not start..

I do not know what it could be wrong. I tried also with the following cloud-init configuration:

```yaml
#cloud-config
mounts:
  - [/dev/disk/by-label/ROOT, /home, btrfs, "defaults,subvol=/@/home"]
users:
  - name: ${username}
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ${ssh_pub_key}

hostname: ${hostname}
```

I do not understand what prevents MicroOS instance to start...

Comment: Can you provide cloud-init logs?

Comment: I found that it is due to the limited disk size. The root disk is 10GB and the image requires more than 25... It is weird since the image is just 390MB...

Comment: It's probably some qcow2 image which expands to the 25 GB, I assume. That's quite a lot for a "MicroOS". Can you provide some details about the image? Maybe that's worth a bug report.

Comment: I'm using just [this](https://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/appliances/openSUSE-MicroOS.x86_64-OpenStack-Cloud.qcow2) image from the [official website](https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:MicroOS#Cloud-Init_Based_Configuration). It is the Base System one (not ContainerHost). I uploaded it to Glance without any special detail to show.